# Reloading .env variables without restarting server (Laravel 5, shared hosting)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, dreamhost

My Laravel 5 has run OK until the database was configured, then found this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Doing some research it seems that I configured MySQL access too late, so I should restart the server in order to get the correct environment variables. Well, I'm using Dreamhost's shared server and I just can't do that.

How should I fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to restart webserver in order to make Laravel reread it's .env file. Laravel does it during every run.

Comment: @max.lanin so then if that's not the problem, if the credentials are correct, what is the problem? I'm running `php artisan migrate` so that I apply the migration

Answer (score -11, accepted):

In `config/database.php` I changed the default DB connection from mysql to sqlite. I deleted the `.env` file (actually renamed it) and created the sqlite file with `touch storage/database.sqlite`. The migration worked with sqlite.

Then I switched back the `config/database.php` default DB connection to mysql and recovered the `.env` file. The migration worked with mysql.

It doesn't make sense I guess. Maybe was something serverside.

Comment: Even though it solved your problem, you shouldn't mark a "hack" as an answer - it encourages bad practices

Answer (score 115):

If you have run `php artisan config:cache` on your server, then your Laravel app could cache outdated config settings that you've put in the `.env` file.

Run `php artisan config:clear` to fix that.

Comment: Running `php artisan config:cache` actually *clears the cache* and *rebuilds it*, so I'd recommend that instead of just `config:clear` if you want to keep using the cache. **BUT** TIL that if you use the `env()` function outside of the cache files, you'll get `NULL` values when your config is cached. So make sure to ONLY use `env()` inside the files in your cache directory

Answer (score 39):

I know this is old, but for local dev, this is what got things back to a production .env file:

```
rm bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

then

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: The docs specifically state "You should typically run the php artisan config:cache command as part of your production deployment routine. The command should not be run during local development"

Answer (score 20):

It's possible that your configuration variables are cached. Verify your `config/app.php` as well as your `.env` file then try

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

on the command line.

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that. Anyway, if `.env` variables override `config/app.php` variables why should I check this file?

Comment: They don't. The `config/app.php` file use them with the `env()` function. All config files do, really. So I'd check the `config/database.php` to see if the calls to `env()` use the correct names.

Comment: Let's see, if I have the app working locally with apache I should only tweak some values in the `.env` file in the server, right? And if nothing is changed inside the `config/`files everything should be working I guess. There's something I'm missing damn

Answer (score 17):

To be clear there are 4 types of caches you can clear depending upon your case.

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

You can run the above statement in your console when you wish to clear the application cache. What it does is that this statement clears all caches inside storage\framework\cache.

```
php artisan route:cache
```

This clears your route cache. So if you have added a new route or have changed a route controller or action you can use this one to reload the same.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

This will clear the caching of the env file and reload it

```
php artisan view:clear
```

This will clear the compiled view files of your application.

### For Shared Hosting

Most of the shared hosting providers don't provide SSH access to the systems. In such a case you will need to create a route and call the following line as below:

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    return "All cache cleared";
});
```

Answer (score 7):

A short solution:

```
use Dotenv;

with(new Dotenv(app()->environmentPath(), app()->environmentFile()))->overload();
with(new LoadConfiguration())->bootstrap(app());
```

In my case I needed to re-establish database connection after altering .env programmatically, but it didn't work , If you get into this trouble try this

```
app('db')->purge($connection->getName());
```

after reloading .env , that's because Laravel App could have accessed the default connection before and the `\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager` needs to re-read config parameters.

Comment: It works but I had to use these two imports: 
`use Dotenv\Dotenv; use Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration;`

Comment: When it comes to the database `DB::reconnect();` did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

In case anybody stumbles upon this question who cannot reload their webserver (long running console command like a queue runner) or needs to reload their .env file mid-request, i found a way to properly reload .env variables in laravel 5.

```
use Dotenv;
use InvalidArgumentException;

try {
    Dotenv::makeMutable();
    Dotenv::load(app()->environmentPath(), app()->environmentFile());
    Dotenv::makeImmutable();
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    //
}
```

Comment: my laravel doesn't seem to be able to import Dotenv by default

Answer (score 1):

This is the only question I could find relating to reloading `.env` and thus `config($key)` values on an existing app instance, but many of these answers should probably live on a different question.

I got the following to work for a Laravel 6.x application, while trying to make an artisan command use my cypress environment variables.

For context `$this->laravel === app()`.

```php
    /**
     * Make the application use the cypress environment variables
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function enableCypressEnv()
    {
        // Get all of the original values from config. We need to do this because
        // rebuilding config will skip packages.
        $old = app(Repository::class)->all();

        // Change the applications env file
        $this->laravel->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.cypress');

        // Reload the app's environment variables 
        Dotenv::create(
            $this->laravel->environmentPath(),
            $this->laravel->environmentFile(),
            Env::getFactory()
        )->overload();

        // Force config to be rebuitl with new env
        (new LoadConfiguration())->bootstrap($this->laravel);
        
        // Get all of the new values from buidling with new env
        $new = app(Repository::class)->all();

        // Merge the new values over the old distinctly
        $merged = array_merge_recursive_distinct($old, $new);

        // Get the applications configuration instance
        $config = config();

        // Overwrite all of the values in the container in accordance with the merged values
        foreach ($merged as $key => $value) {
            $config->set([$key => $value]);
        }
    }
```

Shoutout to the answers above for pointing me in the right direction, but I will include my answer here as none of them worked perfectly for me.

Comment: If you are wondering why one might want to do this, I have created the ability for cypress to access config file values by exporting them to a json file. Obviously this file will need to be built with the correct .env values configured. 

Since I will often be running this locally, I don't want to have to constantly rename my .env values, instead I can just let the command do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

A variant of [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50289263/3135371), including DB reload, tested and working on Laravel 10:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Env;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration;
use Dotenv\Dotenv;

$start_connection = env('DB_CONNECTION');
app()->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.myotherenv');
Dotenv::create(Env::getRepository(), app()->environmentPath(), app()->environmentFile())->load();
(new LoadConfiguration())->bootstrap(app());
app('db')->purge($start_connection);
```

[Here more details](https://blog.madbob.org/destroy-the-laravel-environment/).